# SSH Connection refused, even though the openssh-server daemon is running

Tags: pi-2, ssh, ubuntu

I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu Mate on my Raspberry Pi 2.

Installed `openssh-server` (in fact it was already installed), and changed the port to be `10022`.

However, I cannot access the Pi, from the netowork, neither from the same machine (the Pi itself):

```
$ ping 192.168.2.130 
PING 192.168.2.130 (192.168.2.130): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.130: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=165.807 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.130: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=257.509 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.130: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=170.881 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.130: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.686 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.130 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.686/148.971/257.509/92.516 ms
$ ssh 192.168.2.130 -p 10022
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.130 port 10022: Connection refused
```

How to solve this? Why does it appear?

On a different machine, connected on the same network and everything works fine.

Comment: Did you restart the SSH Daemon after changing the port?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I restarted the pi...

Comment: What is the ouput of `systemctl status ssh sshd`. If it's not enabled run `sudo systemctl enable --now ssh*`.

Comment: @jake They both are enabled but they say _cannot load host key ..._.

Comment: @jake That was useful to debug -- I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` (to regenerate the host keys) and then rebooted and it works now. I assume somehow these keys were not there after the installation. You can post an answer if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To troubleshoot your problem run `systemctl status ssh`. You can see from the output if the ssh server is running and enabled and also see the most recent lines from the log.

`journalctl -e -u ssh.service` could also be helpful to find the issue. It will show everything logged regarding the specified unit.

As we clarified in the comments you found following error `cannot load host key` which could be solved by regenerating the host key file: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH is not enabled in your raspberry pi. Access the root directory of SD card and create a file named “ssh” with no extension and back into you pi and reboot. This should tell you pi to enable ssh.

Comment: That is true for Raspbian, but is it true for Ubuntu?

Comment: Nick, I tried that, but unfortunately it does not make any change...

Comment: This answer should be removed because it ignores the context of the question. Also, there's no such thing as "the root directory of SD card".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry didn't notice that you had Ubuntu Mate on your raspberry pi.  Have you tried the following commands to reinstalled openssh-server.

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
# I rebooted system after install
sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/921258/how-to-enable-ssh-on-boot-in-ubuntu-mate

Comment: Please don't make a new answer. Instead edit your first answer and correct it.